# Sql Server disable index statements occasionally hung during run

Tags: sql-server, indexing

During the initial ETL load (SSIS) i run a stored procedure that disables all my non clustered indexes on the db.

After data load i rebuild them.

Part of the script:

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_GR_F0901D] ON [dbo].[GR_F0901D] DISABLE;
ALTER INDEX [IX_UA_F0901_FACT] ON [dbo].[UA_F0901] DISABLE;
ALTER INDEX [IX_UA_F0901D] ON [dbo].[UA_F0901D] DISABLE;
ALTER INDEX [IX_Gr_F42119] ON [dbo].[GR_F42119] DISABLE;
```

2-3 times per week this process runs indefinitely and i cant find out why.

Today i restarted sql server and run it again and succedded.

What could be wrong?

Should i go with the drop/create instead of disable/rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're being blocked. Next time this happens, take a look at the sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks view and see what is blocking the disable index statement.

Comment: do you think that they could compete with each other? I mean do they execute sequentially or not?

Comment: I wouldn't expect that they compete with each other. My guess is that your have another query (i.e. a select or similar) running that's preventing the schema lock.

Comment: I see but the strange thing that it seems that it does this in some of the indexes not all...and not the same indexes everytime it is happening...

Comment: I hear you. It's frustrating when behavior is inconsistent, but that's the nature of the beast sometimes. Approach it like a scientist; form a hypothesis, make observations, etc. Keep a cool head and you'll have it solved in no time.

Comment: ok can you be more specific about the dm_os_waiting_tasks? What i am looking for? lines that something do NOT change over time?

Comment: I've created a chat room here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69215/sql-server-disable-index-statements-occasionally-hung-during-run. I suspect we're going to have to go into a little more than comments here are usually for.